# bcm2835_init: Unable to open /dev/mem: Permission denied

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi

I try to use a DHT11 sensor on my raspberry pi 3 using a package https://www.npmjs.com/package/rpi-dht-sensor. Anyway, I get this error:

'bcm2835_init: Unable to open /dev/mem: Permission denied'

How can I give permission to bcm2835? Or how do I solve this problem?

I'm new to the raspberry pi and linux.

Here is my code

```
const rpiDhtSensor = require('rpi-dht-sensor');
const dht = new rpiDhtSensor.DHT11(2);

function dhtRead (){
    let readout = dht.read();

    console.log('Temperature: ' + readout.tempraturetoFixed(2) + 'C');
    console.log('Humidity: '+ readout.humidity.toFixed(2) + '%');

    setTimeout(dhtRead, 5000);
}

dhtRead();
```

Here is the whole error

```
bcm2835_init: Unable to open /dev/mem: Permission denied
/home/pi/Documents/javaScript/greenhouse/node_modules/rpi-dht-sensor/main.js:7
        return binding.readSpec(type, pin);
                       ^

TypeError: Failed to initialize
    at DHT.read (/home/pi/Documents/javaScript/greenhouse/node_modules/rpi-dht-sensor/main.js:7:18)
    at dhtRead (/home/pi/Documents/javaScript/greenhouse/index.js:7:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/Documents/javaScript/greenhouse/index.js:15:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

Comment: Which command gives that error?

Comment: @JackBashford my command is 'node index.js'

Comment: Run the app as root then. Or use a library which doesn't require to run with privileged access.

Comment: @emix How do I run the app as root? I'm totally new to this

Comment: Try putting `sudo` in front of your command, that should run it with root access.

Comment: New to what? Linux? :D Run as root or use sudo.

Comment: @emix sorry for not specifing it. Yes, I am new to Linux and raspberry pi.

Comment: The sudo command worked. Thx